# How to handle webpage pop up in Selenium Webdriver which will close after performing action

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I have button in a webpage. Upon clicking that button a pop up will open to select some info. Once I select the info from the pop up then it will get closed automatically.
I tried to handle it in following way:

```
 public void selectCustomerFromPopUp(String Customer)
{
    //By clickSelectCustomerIcon=By.xpath("//*     [@id='dDiv']/table[6]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a/img");
    Set<String> ids=driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> getId=ids.iterator();
    String quoteInfoWindow=getId.next();
    String selectCustomerPopUp=getId.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(selectCustomerPopUp);
    WebElement customerSelectTable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bsData']/table[2]"));
    List<WebElement>rows=customerSelectTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for(WebElement eachrow:rows)
    {
        List<WebElement> column=eachrow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for(WebElement text:column)
        {
            if(text.getText().contains(Customer))
            {
                text.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

But in the console I am seeing target window already closed.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no          such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
(Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
```

Comment: Is it a browser popup or a system popup? If it's an OS popup, then Selenium can't handle it... you'll need some additional tools.

Comment: It's a browser pop up.. Not system pop up.